# Error en calcular operación en constructor sobrecargado

Tags: c#

El problemas es cuando se ingresando dos números por la ventana, solo calcular la resta y no la suma.

**Clase Numero:**

```
public class Numero
{
    double  suma,resta;
    string salida;


    public Numero(double num1, double num2)
    {
        suma = num1+num2;
    }
    public Numero(double num1, string num2)
    {
        resta = num1-double.Parse(num2);
    }
    public string Imprimir()
    {
        salida = "La suma es:" + suma + "\r\nLa resta es:"+resta;
        return salida;
    }

}
```

**Principal:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ejercicio01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Numero entero;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            entero = new Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), txtNum2.Text);

            entero = new Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), double.Parse(txtNum2.Text));

            txtResultado.Text = entero.Imprimir();
        }

        private void BtnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtNum2.Clear();
            txtNum1.Clear();

            txtResultado.Clear();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes ser mas especifica y decir cual es el error y cual es lo esperado ?

Comment: El problema es que al ingresar dos números  quiero  que calcular la suma y resta, pero que sea por constructores sobrecargados. Y el problemas es que cuando escribo                                                      entero = new Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), txtNum2.Text);              
El cual realizará la suma, no lo hace
Y este que realiza la resta sí                                                                                                 entero = new Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), double.Parse(txtNum2.Text));

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Darian el error es muy simple estas creando el objeto entero en esta linea

```
entero = new Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), txtNum2.Text);
```

utilizando el constructor que realiza la resta, para luego sobrescribir de nuevo el objeto `entero` al realizar un nuevo `new`  esta vez con el constructor que realiza la suma:

```
entero = new Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), double.Parse(txtNum2.Text));
```

Cada vez que realizas un `new`estas creando un objeto nuevo, por lo tanto el objeto que creaste anteriormente se sobrescribe con el nuevo. Lo que necesitas es un objeto de la clase `Numero`que realice las dos operaciones.

Por lo tanto tu clase `Numero` necesita realizar las dos operaciones en el constructor (se puede hacer de muchas otras maneras) pero por ejemplo podría ser así:

```
    public class Numero
{
    double suma, resta;
    string salida;


    public Numero(double num1, double num2)
    {
        suma = num1 + num2;
        resta = num1 - num2;
    }

    public Numero(string num1, string num2) : this(double.Parse(num1), double.Parse(num2))
    {



    }

    public string Imprimir()
    {
        salida = "La suma es:" + suma + "\r\nLa resta es:" + resta;
        return salida;
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder!  pero quisiera que solo a través del constructor se realicen la suma y la resta. No por métodos diferentes.

Comment: Pues simplemente mete el contenido de las funciones suma y resta en los constructores. No es lo mas limpio pero te lo pongo como segunda opción.

Comment: Voy a ponerte otra forma mas limpia de hacerlo, edito mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

entonces creo que el error es simple, lo que sucede es que lo mas probable es que si la haga, solo que cuando haces la resta, sobre escribes la varuable, entonces seria asi:

```
private void BtnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//creas la instancia de la clase
        entero = new Numero();
//invocas el primer metodo
        entero.Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), txtNum2.Text);
//invocas el segundo metodo
        entero.Numero(double.Parse(txtNum1.Text), double.Parse(txtNum2.Text));
//invocas el metodo de imprimir
        txtResultado.Text = entero.Imprimir();
    }

}
```

espero te sriva, me cuentas...

Comment: Pero el constructor no puede ser escrito asi, verdad? poniendo entero. ya que no lo reconoce como metodo